# Is there a way to pass the redirect_uri through the state parameter and access the said parameter in the callback endpoint?

Tags: auth0, restify

I've been trying to implement a redirect after the user is successfully authenticated to the service that utilized our authentication service.

To do so, I've tried passing the redirect_uri through the state parameter shown below:

```
let state1 = {
    clientId: clientId,
    clientSecret: clientSecret,
    redirectUri: redirectUri
}
passport.authenticate(
   'auth0',
    {
         responseType: 'code',
         scope: 'openid profile email',
         state: JSON.stringify(state1)
    },
    function(err, user, info) {
         res.send(user)
    })(req, res, next)
```

I've expected the state containing the redirect_uri, client_id and client_secret to be accessible in the callback endpoint, but it's just the successful authentication code that is in the URL of the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. It uses a nonce to secure the info against CSRF attacks. Please take a look at this doc:

https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/redirect-users